# How to get xpath for this tag?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to select first element with valid Email id from these tags .

```
 <div class="email">adsdasdsa@gmail.com</div>
 <div class="email">adsdasdsa</div>
 <div class="email">asdsa@gmail.com</div>
```

Currently am using this xpath: `//div[@class='email' and contains(text()='.com')]` . But I could not select the element. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
//div[@class='email' and contains(.,'.com')][1]
```

Comment: It wont select first div with _valid email id_, it will select first div which contains `.com`

Comment: It would select based on the `class` name and which contains `.com`

Comment: OP wants `I am trying to select first element with valid Email id..`

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath should be `//div[@class='email' and contains(text(),'.com')]`. It will get first occurrence of this xpath. If you need exactly first or third element add `[1]` or `[3]` which specifies number of occurrence.

Comment: It wont select first div with _valid email id_, it will select first div which contains `.com`

Comment: Agree, then we need to clarify what is "valid email" for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
//div[1][starts-with(@class,'email')and contains(.,'.com')]
```